# Show print dialog box to print Excel sheet from MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I want to print Excel sheet (Single sheet) which is stored in a path of local computer using a click of button on MS Access form. For some business reasons I need to provide flexibility to show the print setup dialog box which we normally get if we were printing Excel sheet from outside, so that user can select the printer, select what part of sheet to print, copies to print etc. I currently have code as shown below:-

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    'wks is already set to Excel sheet which needs to be printed
    wks.PrintOut
End Sub
```

I am trying to also use something like as shown below , but not sure how to connect the Printout method with xlDialogPrint

```
 ExcelApp.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

I am struggling with what code would do that in MS Access VBA.

Comment: If you want to allow user to select printer and other print settings then how could you automate Printout? I expect user will have to click Print from Print interface.

Answer (score 2):

The follow code will open Excel then open print interface to allow user to make choices for printing whatever sheet has focus.

```
Sub PrintSheet()
Dim xl As Excel.Application, wb As Excel.Workbook
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\filepath\filename.xlsx")
xl.Visible = True
xl.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks June7 for the response. I am able to get the print dialog box using the code suggested by you, however the execution does not stop for the user to  take action and proceeds further and moves to next line of code which I have written to close the worksheet and quit the Excel application. How to pause till the user has either canceled the print dialog box or the user is done with printing.

Comment: also is it possible to just get the print dialog box without using xl.Visible = True . I mean is it possible that Excel interface continues to remain hidden and only print dialog box of Excel is visible. Thanks

Comment: I don't think can pause. Either user gets control or they don't. If the app is not visible how would you expect its features to be visible? You can try commenting `xl.Visible = True` and place a breakpoint on Quit line and see what happens. Don't think you will appreciate.